# Ошибка при конвертации в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть объект `data`, который нужно отсортировать (меню с одной ступенью вложенности).
Делаю это таким методом:

```
sortingData (data){
    var out = [];
    for(let i in data){
        if(!data[i].pid){
            out.push(data[i]);
        }
    }

    for(var i in data){
        for(var j in out){
            if(out[j].id == data[i].pid){
                if(!$.isset(out[j].childs)){
                    out[j].childs = [];
                }
                out[j].childs.push(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return JSON.stringify(out);
}
```

На этапе конвертирования в json получаю ошибку: `Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Я понял что дело тут в циклических ссылках друг на друга в объекте `data`, но, не пойму как мне избавиться от них чтобы получить нормальный объект `out`, как бы я не создавал новый объект, все-равно в json он его не хочет конвертить. Вопрос в том, как создать объект `out`, чтобы он не содержал в себе циклические ссылки?

Comment: Можно увидеть строку out?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас циклические ссылки в `data`. Что говорит `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: JFYI, множественное число от `child` — `children`.

Comment: @МаксимДробышев out = false, т.к. ошибка. data - обычный объект, из него делается out, см. цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче говоря, не стал я возиться и просто по-клонировал объекты `data[i]` когда делал пуш в `out`:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
            var key, clone = {};
            for(key in obj) if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) clone[key] = obj[key];
            return clone;
        }
```

Comment: как этот код связан с кодом в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy, никак, это я добавил и написал куда именно